# Cannot import name from test1

Tags: python

```
#algorithm_time.py
from timeit import *

def test1():
    l = []
    for i in range(1000):
        l = l + [i]


t1 = Timer("test1()","from __main__ import test1")
print("concat",t1.timeit(number=1000),"milliseconds")
```

when I run this python script in terminal, it went well and I can get what I want . 
but when I am trying to run this script in python console(I am using pycharm), I tried: import algorithm_time, I got an ImportError:cannot import name test1. I was wondering why this would happen.
Thanks guys!

Comment: I don't think `__main__` is initially defined when you run the console

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you saying that I should define another def __main__(), which include the test1() function I wrote before? I am pretty new to python...

Comment: I'd try the answer already posted first. If that does not work you can try `import __main__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run following script,

```
from timeit import *

def test1():
    l = []
    for i in range(1000):
        l = l + [i]


t1 = Timer("test1()", "from algorithm_time import test1")
print("concat",t1.timeit(number=1000),"milliseconds")
```

Simple thing is, when you are running on python cli, `from __main__` means py cli's namespace.

Comment: by python cli, do you mean python console?

Comment: Yes, Correct. I mean python console.